# PDO bind parameter doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I have a query like:

```
$stmt = $db->query('
    SELECT e.id
    FROM `entity` e
    WHERE e.deleted = 0 AND e.published = 1 AND e.date <= CURDATE() ' .
          ( !empty($_SESSION['filter']) ? ' AND e.category = :category' : '' )
);

if (!empty($_SESSION['filter'])) {
    $stmt->bindValue('category', $_SESSION['filter'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
}

$entities = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

I've some entries in catgeory `1` and `$_SESSION['filter']` is set:

```
string(1) "1"
```

But it doesn't load any entries nor do I get any error.

What I tried too:

- rename `category` to something else, like `myvalue`
- setting up a new variable: `$x = 1; $stmt->bindValue('category', $x, PDO::PARAM_INT);`
- editing the query directly: `' AND e.category = 1'` or `' AND e.category = $_SESSION['filter']'`

Out of all possibilites only *the last one* worked. It's also the one I actually don't want to use. How can I fix this?

Comment: you have to `execute()` statement before you can `fetchAll()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PDO::query() executes an SQL statement in a single function call, returning the result set (if any) returned by the statement as a PDOStatement object.`

Your query is already executed. Binding values takes no effect.

You should prepare your query first.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('
    SELECT e.id
    FROM `entity` e
    WHERE e.deleted = 0 AND e.published = 1 AND e.date <= CURDATE() ' .
      ( !empty($_SESSION['filter']) ? ' AND e.category = :category' : '' )
);
```

Comment: Ahhhhhh, of course. I think I should ta a break after coding the whole day. I absolute didn't `execute` it. Thanks. Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a colon in this line:

```
$stmt->bindValue('category', $_SESSION['filter'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Should be:

```
$stmt->bindValue(':category', $_SESSION['filter'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Edit: I missed the most obvious issue. Please see u_mulder's answer as well.